# Creating one jquery code for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs with check box values in it. Currently this is the way i'm capturing the checked values in the textarea. But i have to write the button click code for every div that has this check box values. Is there a  way to make that js code unified for divs. So that I do not have to end up with very huge JS file for this purpose.

`$("#sport").click(function() { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); $(p).html("I don't play these games"); $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); });`

I would like to make this logic common for all other divs. I can't seem to get my head around this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).fadeIn("slow").siblings().fadeOut("fast");
    if ($("#"+divname).height() >= $(window).height()) {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $("#"+divname) ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
  
  });
  
  
 $("#sport").click(function() { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); $(p).html("I  play these games"); $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); }); 
                               
  $("#sport1").click(function() { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); $(p).html("I don't play these games"); $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); }); 
                                                       
                                 
 $("#drinks").click(function() { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); $(p).html("I drink these"); $.each($("input[name='drink']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); }); 
 
  $("#drinks1").click(function() { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); $(p).html("I don't drink these"); $.each($("input[name='drink']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); });                                
                                
//Clear Textarea
 $('#myModal1').on('hidden', function() {
    clear()
  });
```

```html
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="checkid"   style="min-width: 100%" rows = "20" class="auto">
</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" name="div100" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item1</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div200" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item2</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div300" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item3</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div400" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item4</font></a>

<div id="div100" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div1" >item1-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div2" >item1-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div3" >item1-desc3</a></li1>
  
<div id="div200" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div4" > item2-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div5" >item2-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div6" >item2-desc3</a></li1>
    
<div id="div300" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div7" > item3-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div8" >item3-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div9" >item3-desc3</a></li1>
      
<div id="div400" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div10" > item4-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div11" >item4-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div12" >item4-desc3</a></li1>
  
<div id="div1" style="display:none" align="left">
 <form>
  <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="sport">I play these</button>
    <button type="button" id="sport1">I dont play these</button>
   
</form>
<div id="div2" style="display:none" align="left">
 <form>
  <h3>Select your favorite drinks:</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Coke" name="drink"> 
    Coke</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Pepsi" name="drink"> Pepsi</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mountain Dew" name="drink"> Mountain Dew</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Beer" name="drink"> Beer</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Lemonade" name="drink"> Lemonade</label>
  
  <br>
  <button type="button" id ="drinks">I drink these</button>
   <button type="button" id ="drinks1">I don't drink these</button>
</form>
<div id="div3" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div3 contents-->
<div id="div4" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div4 contents-->
  
  <!--So on-->
```

Comment: Use parentNode and children technique to get the exact element.

Answer (score 3):

Create a common function and use it like,

```
function thankyou(type){
    var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); 
    $(p).html("I don't play these games"); 
    $.each($("input[name='"+type+"']:checked"), function() { 
      $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + 
         "--------------------------" + '\n' +
         "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n'
         + "-----------------------------------"); 
    });
}

$("#sport").click(function() { 
    thankyou('sport');
});                                
$("#drinks").click(function() { 
    thankyou('drink');
});
```

**Another best way** I think is add an extra attribute like `data-type` to all your buttons for which you want to call thankyou function like,

```
<button type="button" data-type="drink" id ="drinks">Get Values</button>
<button type="button" data-type="sport" id ="drinks">Get Values</button>
```

Now, in jquery code change it like,

```
$('button[data-type]').on('click',function(){
    type= $(this).data('type');// will give sport,drink, etc
    var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); 
    $(p).html("I don't play these games"); 
    $.each($("input[name='"+type+"']:checked"), function() { 
      $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + 
         "--------------------------" + '\n' +
         "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n'
         + "-----------------------------------"); 
    });
});
```

Also, I think the name (sport, drink, etc) should be an array like `sport[]`, `drink[]` if you are using any server side code for these fields.

Comment: I have other divs as well and the webpage might end getting additional similar divs. I was thinking about making the entire logic common. I though this logic. But i have to enter this everytime I add divs. Or is there a way to make the `$("#sport").click(function() { 
    thankyou('sport');
});` common

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can add a class to all related button and bind event handler using class.
For example, add `class="action"` to buttons like below

```
<button type="button" id ="sport" class="action">Get Values</button>
<button type="button" id ="drinks" class="action">Get Values</button>
```

add click handler as, replace input name with id of clicked button

```
$(".action").click(function() { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); $(p).html("I don't play these games"); $.each($("input[name='" + this.id + "']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); });
```

**EDIT** - As OP cannot add class to button, use below code with selector as button inside form. This will work for both the buttons in the form, and OP does not need to change the code if many other similar form get added to the page.

```
$("form button").click(function() { 
     var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid"); 
     $(p).html($(this).text()); 
      $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
     $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); 
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a good thing, but im using bootstrap. So the buttons has the bootstrap class . `<button type="button" id ="sport" class="btn btn-success btn-lg>Get Values</button>`

Comment: that is the reason I'm using id, by which i have to enter the code every time i add divs

Comment: You can use `$("form button")` selector to bind click event as it seems like you have only one button inside form. Check my edit in answer

Comment: Sorry  @ Bhushan Kawadkar. I thought I edited my question, there is actually 2 buttons in the form. each with an unique and that is why  had to enter the Jquery code every time. So Sorry. I edited my question. please have a look again.

Comment: will button sequence be same always? I mean to say, your button will be the first one out of two buttons?

Comment: Yeah. So every div will have 2 button one saying "I do these..."  and the other "I dont do these..". I was looking to create 2 common jquery logics to append the values with some predefined texts like... " I dont play these.." and the checked values.. and then "i play these..." and the check values. I would be calling based on button clicks

Comment: I have updated my edit in answer. Same code will work for both buttons in side form. try it and let me know

Comment: Sorry, it was not capturing the values. the modal was was coming up empty